# How to sort files by date in Safari file picker

Tags: safari

When I am uploading file(s) in Safari using file picker, I have 3 view options (icons, list, columns). I cannot figure out how to sort files by date (e.g. date modified) when I am in columns view. Please refer to the screenshots below for the clarification (p.s. I am referring to **sorting**, *not* grouping):

[image: Icons view]

[image: List view]

[image: Column view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Sort by' drop menu is at the top of your file-picker - using a crop of your own pic as example...

[image]

you get these choices...

[image]

Comment: When I choose Date options, it doesn't sort but actually groups the files. I am looking to sort files by Date options, **not** group them

Comment: Then don't use column view.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Then the answer to your question is "it can't be done".

Comment: Dumb feature not to have. I mean dumb not to have it. The default sort seems to be completely worthless.